# How To Update MacBook Pro (13-inch, Early 2011) from macOS High Sierra (Version 10.13.6) To macOS Big Sur (Version 11)?

Tags: macbook-pro, high-sierra, software-update, upgrade, big-sur

I have tried everything to update my MacBook Pro (13-inch, Early 2011), which is currently running macOS High Sierra (version 10.13.6), but it's not working.

I can't install some apps because of the version.

[image: Adobe Lightroom update failure]

How can I update to macOS Big Sur (version 11)?.

Comment: Is Lightroom just an example app, or should your question be "How to install a version of Lightroom which is compatible with High Sierra"?

Comment: Your Mac has the model identifier MacBookPro8,1.  According to [this Open Core webpage](https://github.com/dortania/OpenCore-Legacy-Patcher/issues/108) your Mac has be successfully tested to run Big Sur through the use of the Open Core patcher. I have never used Open Core, so I do not know how good it is. I just thought I would point this out as maybe an option.

Comment: Lightroom is just an Example of apps that can't be installed on my mac version, Yes i have heard about Open Core patcher, but i don't known how efficient it is?.
 Does anyone know how efficient Open Core patcher is, coz i guess thats the only way i could update my MacOS version to Big Sur?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. High Sierra is the last supported OS for a 2011 MacBook Pro. See [Hardware_compatibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS#Hardware_compatibility).

There are some hacks, such as those by [DosDude1](https://dosdude1.com/catalina/), and you *might* be able to get Catalina running, but it will have some issues and be dog slow, so it is not worth it really.

Comment: Ok thank you, i will look into this

Comment: Don't forget to upvote if you find the answer useful and/or mark it as the accepted answer. Thanks.